# How to show the data from a custom list in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom list in sharepoint which contains several fields including a body, image etc. How can I show the same in the sharepoint website ? Do I need a webpart to do that ?If yes, how to render the large body part which contains images & text in the site?

Answer (score 1):

You can use List webpart for this and then you can render the view by adding some JavaScript and CSS.

[Customize the rendering of a List View in Sharepoint 2013: Displaying List Items in Accordion](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/04/14/customize-the-rendering-of-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-2013-displaying-list-items-in-accordion/)

[Custom JS Rendering in SharePoint 2013](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524962/JSLink-Custom-JS-Rendering-in-SharePoint-2013)

[Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a/sourcecode?fileId=96782&pathId=1717720622)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you show me a sample ? (I'm new to sharepoint. :()

Comment: It will be difficult to add the code here. BTW you can have a look through the links which I have added in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

iv explained it here in detail:

[WebPart getting started!](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84536/webpart-getting-started/84543#84543)

its simple and fast to create it yourself using a custom webpart!

also look here for more on webparts and getting started

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx